# Is there any significance to the "big name toys" in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

Scattered in among the random junk in *Fallout 4* are a couple of recurring toys, that are of rather large size. You find parts for a Giddyup Buttercup (and a complete one, at one point), a lot of Jangles the Moon Monkey, and even some alien toy.

Is there any significance to collecting these beyond just their value as junk parts? Should I bother to pick them up or keep any around outside of my workshops?

Comment: I don't remember there being any reason to collect these other than for junk.  There may have been a side quest for finding a complete intact Giddyup Buttercup, but I think that is scripted.

Comment: If i remember correctly, the Giddyup parts either sell for a lot of caps, or give a good chunk of resources.

Comment: I can only find info on what parts they break down into, and that "they're worth a lot". I'd have to research in-game to find the price, and I don't find myself playing too often. If I get time this weekend I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the wiki and most junk items have no "real use" besides being scrapped for crafting or use for decoration. If you want to check on any items and their use (especially the junk) just got to [the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Fallout_4_junk_items) I used.